# Extracting LSB and MSB on Z80 Assembly

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, z80

Lets say i have a data (15H) on memory 0040.

My question is, how an I extract that most significant and least significant bit for further usage?

I have lookup on the [Z80 User manual](http://www.zilog.com/docs/z80/um0080.pdf) and found nothing. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: To get the LSB use bitwise `AND` with 1. To get the MSB, shift right by 7. Those are the general ways, not specific to Z80.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but i'm really looking for the details on Z80 Assembly.

Comment: Z80 does have an `AND` so that's easy. Instead of a shift right, you can use a rotate left `RLCA` to move the MSB into LSB and then `AND` as previously. Or, if you want the result in the carry flag, you don't need the `AND` and can use a rotate right `RRCA` for the LSB. There is also the `BIT` instruction for testing a bit directly via the zero flag.

Comment: I'm affraid i haven't understand that answer. So let's say i wanted to get the LSB. Does AND instruction will give me that immidiately?

Comment: You have at least 3 options after you loaded the byte into `A`: 1) `AND a, #1` and then your LSB is in `A`. 2) `RRCA` and then your LSB is in `CF`. 3) `BIT 0, A` and then your bit is in `ZF` negated.

Comment: Totally Get it! Can you explain it too for the MSB ?

Comment: `RLCA` and then your MSB is in `CF`. Follow by `AND a, #1` to keep it in `A`. Alternatively, use `BIT 7, A` to put it in `ZF` negated.

Comment: Fantastic thank you!, If you add this to the answer it will be more helpful for the others

Comment: There are several good Z80 books available for free online.  Find one or two and learn from them.  If you have this question and continue with the Z80, you will doubtless have others.  One by Leventhal is a masterpiece of Z80 wisdom.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but I don't understand why the down vote? I think I already did a research before asking a question.

Comment: I didn't vote down, but you didn't show what you tried from the user manual, and why you think that it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to wrote down what @Jester already explained to me

#### how to get the LSB

1. using AND

```
LD A, 1
LD B, 19H ;The data
AND B     ;LSB is at register A
```

2. using RRCA
3. using BIT

#### how to get the MSB

1. using RLCA followed by AND
2. using BIT

Comment: You don't need to `LD A, 1` separately, just `ld b, 19h` / `AND 1` .  http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/instructions-set:and shows that Z80's AND instruction can have immediate operand.